# Why is a function not being accessed when using onClick?

Tags: typescript, next.js13

I have recently tried switching from javascript to typescript and have run into an early issue I cannot solve. Here is the code:

```
'use client';

import { useMetamask } from '@/hooks/metamask';

export function Connect() {
  const { account } = useMetamask();
  console.log(account)

  const handleConnect = async () => {
    console.log("Test")
    if (!account) {
      try {
        const ethereum = (window as any).ethereum;
        if (ethereum) {
          await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('User denied account access');
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`Already connected with ${account}`);
    }
  };



  return (
      <button type="submit" className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white" onClick={handleConnect}>
        {account ? 'Connected' : 'Connect with MetaMask'}
      </button>
  );
};
```

I am trying to access the handleConnect function after a user click, but I cannot even get the test console log to output. I have also tried the following with no success:

```
// Switched handleConnect to be async function handleConnect() {}
onClick={() => handleConnect()}
```

Is there something I am mising that is causing this not to work?

Comment: does this `console.log("Test")` run?

Comment: @Yilmaz Nope, it does not

Comment: is the page refreshing after you click the button?